# AngularJS Compiling Model Like StackOverflow

Tags: html, angularjs, css

Good day everyone, right now i'm trying to create a textbox like this `(stackoverflow textbox)` using angularJS .. but im having difficulties on doing so , i have to replace `**SOME TEXT HERE**` to `strong SOME TEXT HERE /strong` here's my code ..

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var app = angular.module("appModule", [], function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');
  });

  /* ALLOW ANGULAR TO RENDER HTML OUTPUT */
  app.directive('compile', ['$compile', function($compile) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.$watch(function(scope) {


          return scope.$eval(attrs.compile);
        },
        function(value) {
          element.html(value);
          $compile(element.contents())(scope);
        }
      )
    };
  }]);

  /* CONTROLLER FOR PROFILE TICKER */
  app.controller("ProfileTickerController", function($rootScope, $scope, dataService, FileUploader) {
    // INITIAL VALUES FOR PROFILE TICKER
    $scope.ticker = '';
    $scope.previous = '';
    $scope.edit = false;

    $scope.editTicker = function() {
      $scope.previous = $scope.ticker;
      if ($scope.ticker == "<span class='color-light-grey'>Ticker not set</span>") {
        $scope.ticker = "";
      }
      $scope.edit = true;
    }

    $scope.cancelEdit = function() {
      $scope.ticker = $scope.previous;
      $scope.edit = false;
    }

    $scope.saveTicker = function() {
      if ($scope.ticker == "") {
        $scope.ticker = "<span class='color-light-grey'>Ticker not set</span>";
      }
      $scope.edit = false;
    }

    $scope.$watch('ticker', function() {
      if ($scope.ticker == undefined) {
        $scope.ticker = "";
      }
    })

    $scope.init = function(id) {
      var postData = 'profileID=' + id;

      // SETUP AJAX CONFIG
      var config = {
        "method": "POST",
        "url": "ajax/getTicker.php",
        "data": postData,
        "headers": {
          'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
      };

      // AJAX TO GET PROFILE TICKER
      dataService.ajaxThis(config).then(function mySuccess(response) {
        // CHECK IF AJAX SUCCESSFUL
        if (response.status != 200) {
          console.log('Ajax error! Profile ticker not fetched. Please reload the page and try again.');
        } else {
          // GET PROFILE TICKER
          if (response.data == "") {
            $scope.ticker = "<span class='color-light-grey'>Ticker not set</span>";
          } else {
            $scope.ticker = response.data;
          }

        }
      });
    }

    $scope.$on('profileLoaded', function(e, id) {
      $scope.init(id);
    });
  });
})
```

```css
.textarea-non-resize {
 resize: none;
}

.grey-box {
    background: #efefef;
    border: 1px solid #dedede;
    padding: 10px;
}

#ticker {
 height: 42px;
 background-color: #fff;
    border-top: 1px solid #dedede;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dedede;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>

<script src="script.js"></script>

<body ng-app="appModule" class="ng-scope">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12" ng-controller="ProfileTickerController">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="subject">
                        Ticker 
                        <span ng-show="!edit">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" title="Edit Ticker" ng-click="editTicker()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></a>
                        </span>
                        <span ng-show="edit">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" title="Save Ticker" ng-click="saveTicker()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></a> 
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" title="Cancel" ng-click="cancelEdit()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></a>
                        </span>
                    </label>
        <textarea name="ticker_edit" id="ticker_edit" class="form-control textarea-non-resize" ng-model="ticker" ng-show="edit" placeholder="Customize your ticker here" required cols="50" rows="4" style="margin-bottom: 10px;"></textarea>
        <div class="grey-box">
          Preview:
          <div id="ticker" class="text-center">
            <h3 compile="ticker"></h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

There's a script error here, but it's working fine in my computer. So anyway how would i replace the said string above using that compiler ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using a **Regex** to replace the value before you inject it into the element's HTML?

```js
// replace bold text
value = value.replace(/\*\*(.*)\*\*/g, "<strong>$1</strong>");
```

The above is a simple example and you might need to tweak it a bit to fit your purpose, but the general idea is there.

Comment: actually i've already done it so for the effort .. cheers mate